# pass correct format of date value returned from another function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using V_SQL as parameter which stores SQL query as string and takes DATE input which is returned from another function.

```
Function which is returning date value:
----------------------------------------

FUNCTION RETURN_DATE(V_D DATE) RETURN DATE IS
IS_BUS CHAR(1);
V_CNT NUMBER(5);
V_DT DATE;

BEGIN

    V_DT :=V_D;

    WHILE IS_BUSINESS_DAY(V_DT) = 'N'
        LOOP
            V_DT := V_DT - 1;
        END LOOP;

    IF IS_BUSINESS_DAY(V_DT) = 'Y' THEN
            V_DT := V_DT - 1;
    END IF;

RETURN V_DT;
END RETURN_DATE;
```

```
V_SQL := 'SELECT A.ACCOUNT_TYPE, B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID, B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3, ' || 
'SUM(CURRENT_BAL) AS CB_SUM, SUM(AVG_BAL) AS AB_SUM, B.FLAG1 FROM DAILYGL_TEST A, AL_LOOKUP B '||
'WHERE A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = B.GL_ACCT AND A.AS_OF_DATE =  '|| 
**RETURN_DATE(V_RUN_DATE)** ||
' AND ROWNUM <=15 GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT_TYPE, B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID,B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3, A.AS_OF_DATE, B.FLAG1';
```

```
I am getting date returned as '29-AUG-2019' and when it is being supplied to this V_SQL query, it is throwing 'AUG not valid identifier issue'. Also, Date in AS_OF_DATE column is in MM/DD/YYYY format such 09/02/2019 for 02-SEP-2019.

Could you please help me in editing, formatting this code properly so this error can be removed. Let me know what I should change in RETURN_DATE(V_RUN_DATE) while supplying it to V_SQL.


Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: try adding to_date before passing the return value of the function. like to_date after A.AS_OF_DATE =  '

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling the function is wrong; it shouldn't be concatenated to the main query, but embedded into it. Have a look at this simplified example (line #5 is what you should pay attention to).

```
SQL> create or replace function return_date (v_d in varchar2)
  2    return date
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return to_date(v_d, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> select ename, hiredate from emp where rownum = 1;

ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- -------------------
SMITH      17.12.1980 00:00:00

SQL> declare
  2    v_sql varchar2(500);
  3    l_row emp%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    v_sql := q'[select * from emp where hiredate = return_date('&v_run_date') ]' ||
  6             ' and rownum = 1';
  7    dbms_output.put_Line(v_sql);
  8    execute immediate v_sql into l_row;
  9    dbms_output.put_line(l_row.ename);
 10  end;
 11  /
Enter value for v_run_date: 17.12.1980
select * from emp where hiredate = return_date('17.12.1980')  and rownum = 1
SMITH

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Actually, V_RUN_DATE is run date which user will input whenever he/she runs the proc. I've moved the code inside as you suggested but it is throwing RETURN_DATE is invalid identifier. Also, I'm printing query, using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_SQL), to see what is being passed to AS_OF_DATE. It is showing ' AND A.AS_OF_DATE = RETURN_DATE(V_RUN_DATE)' instead of passing date value in MMDDYYYY format. Could you please suggest how to fix it?

Comment: I modified code I previously posted so that it asks for a date. Note that I've also changed the function which now expects a string (varchar2) in DD.MM.YYYY format (you can change it to something different) and returns date.

Comment: Thanks. I'm supplying date at PROCEDURE POST_DAILY_GL(V_RUN_DATE DATE) AS....Inside this, V_SQL is defined which is using same V_RUN_DATE which is supplied to PROCEDURE POST_DAILY_GL. Based on this, It being passed to function. Code is as following

Comment: PROCEDURE POST_DAILY_GL(V_RUN_DATE DATE) AS


V_IDENTITY_CODE CONSTANT NUMBER(6):=112233;
        V_SQL := '[SELECT A.ACCOUNT_TYPE, B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID, B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3,
                 SUM(CURRENT_BAL) AS CB_SUM, SUM(AVG_BAL) AS AB_SUM, B.FLAG1 FROM DAILYGL_TEST A, AL_LOOKUP B
                 WHERE A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = B.GL_ACCT AND A.AS_OF_DATE = RETURN_DATE('&V_RUN_DATE')]' ||

Comment: Do I still need &V_RUN_DATE. By the way, I am running it on TOAD, ORACLE.

Comment: If it is a procedure and V_RUN_DATE is its parameter, then you don't need `&` (it means that you're required to manually enter its value). For a procedure, you'd `exec post_daily_gl(date '2019-06-24');`